# MS Dynamic AX POS start up error

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am getting following error while starting up POS in MS Dynamics AX. Can someone please help me out?

```
Unable to start the application. The application will shutdown.LSRetailPosis.PosStartupException: The only screen found is the primary display
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Retail.Pos.Services.Peripherals.LoadPeripheral(Int32 peripheralStringId, IPeripheral perphiral)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Retail.Pos.Services.Peripherals.Load()
   at LSRetailPosis.POS.Program.InitializeAndLoadPOS(String[] args, Boolean owned, SplashScreenForm splashScreenForm)
   at LSRetailPosis.POS.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: This isn't exactly code related, but it sounds like it is expecting more than 1 display?

Answer (score 0):

1) Create new Pos profile in Retail Headquater,
2) Run N-Job from retail schedular to push data from Retail Headquater to Retail POS Database
3) Try opening your application pos.exe

Answer (score 0):

The reason is secound display on your PC (with POS) and incorrect setting AX.

1. Check in AX "Retail/Setup/POS/Profiles/Hardware Profiles" section "Dual display\Dual display in use" (set checkbox)
2. On PC (with POS) press "Win + P" and choose "Extend"

also you may get this error if you use RDP for starting up POS